# Parsing JSON in Python: how do I get has_key() working again after a change of format?

Tags: python, json, unicode

I have the following block of Python code:

```
data = json.loads(line)
if data.has_key('derivedFrom'):
     dFin = data['derivedFrom']
     if dFin.has_key('derivedIds'):
```

This used to work fine on a block of JSON like this:

```
"derivedFrom": {"source": "FOO", "model": "BAR", "derivedIds": ["123456"]}
```

Now the format changed to:

```
"derivedFrom": "{\"source\": \"FOO.\", \"model\": \"BAR\", \"derivedIds\": [\"123456\"]
```

And so the last line in the Python block throws the following exception:

```
'unicode' object has no attribute 'has_key'
```

Is there a way to preprocess JSON to make `has_key` work again?

Comment: How did the format change? Also, that block isn't valid JSON.

Comment: The "changed" format is not valid JSON. It won't parse at all.

Comment: And, `foo.has_key(bar)` has been spelled `bar in foo` since at least Python 2.4.

Comment: Why/how did the format change?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
"{\"source\": \"FOO.\", \"model\": ...
```

Is a JSON object inside a JSON string literal. To get at the inner JSON's properties, you'll have to decode it again.

```
data = json.loads(line)
if 'derivedFrom' in data:
    dFin = json.loads(data['derivedFrom'])
    if 'derivedIds' in dFin:
        ....
```

JSON-in-JSON is typically a mistake as there's rarely a need for it - what is producing this output, does it need fixing?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
'derivedIds' in dFin
```

This works both on dictionaries and on unicode, even though with unicode it could give false positives.

A more robust approach could use [Duck Typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing):

```
try:
    dFin = json.loads(data['derivedFrom'])  #assume new format
except TypeError:
    dFin = data['derivedFrom']  #it's already a dict
if 'derivedIds' in dFin: # or dFin.has_key('derivedIds')
    #etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the derivedFrom property from a JSON object to a string.  Strings don't have an attribute named has_key.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the exact same block of code to work, consider slightly adjusting your new format to following:

```
"{\"derivedFrom\": {\"source\": \"FOO.\", \"model\": \"BAR\", \"derivedIds\": [\"123456\"]}}"
```